# I get no error now when i install ssl certificate, but https is not working! I use nginx server under ubuntu 18.04 linux

Tags: nginx, ssl

my ssl file is under nginx /etc/nginx/ssl/default

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443;

    server_name domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/perm_with_key.pem;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _; 

    location / {
       # First attempt to serve request as file, then
       # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.

       #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_connect_timeout 400000;
            proxy_send_timeout 400000;
            proxy_read_timeout 400000;
            send_timeout 400000;

    proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"; 
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
   }
   }
```

i don't know what i am missing here. i got ssl certificate from godaddy.

Could anyone give me solution. Thanks.

Comment: Error logs  or output?

Answer (score 0):

You need separate server blocks for 80 and 443:

```
server {                                                                                                                                                                
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  access_log off;                                                                                                                                             
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;                                                                                                                               
}                                                                                                                                                                   

server {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  listen 443 ssl default_server;
  server_name domain.com _;                                                                                                                  
  <Put the rest of your existing stuff here with only one server_name directive>                                                                                
}
```

This will redirect everything inbound to 80 to 443

Nginx has great documentation. Please bookmark:

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/

Comment: I am sorry not getting your point http2?
Do http stuff here means - can you add code from my question.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: not working still. But i get this error in error.log of nginx -                   SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14209102:SSL routines:tls_early_post_process_client_hello:unsupported protocol) while SSL handshaking, client: 208.93.152.20, server: 0.0.0.0:443

Comment: from sslchecker i get:domain.com resolves to 184.168.131.241
Server Type: nginx/1.12. The certificate was issued by GoDaddy.   
The certificate will expire in 143 days.None of the common names in the certificate match the name that was entered (www.domain.com). You may receive an error when accessing this site in a web browser.  errors.
SANs: shortener.secureserver.net, www.shortener.secureserver.net
Issuer: Starfield Secure Certificate Authority - G2 
the ip-address mentioned is not our ip-address of server. We got certificate from godaddy. " Starfield Secure Certificate Authority - G2"

Comment: we got ssl from godaddy and it will expire after a year only.